# xamarin update TextView in a loop after dellay

Tags: c#, android, for-loop, xamarin, textview

I use Visual Studio. 
I am trying to update a TextView with **i.ToString()** in a for loop after a period of time when button is pressed, but it always show the last value of **i**, I am new to android, and, maybe I miss something. Can anyone explain what i do wrong?

```
namespace MyApp
{
    [Activity(MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class MyActivity : Activity
    {
        public static TextView text1;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyActivity);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            text1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

            btn.Click += delegate
            {
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    text1.Text = i.`ToString`();
                    Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

After i press the button the value of TextView is 4.

P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want to make your delegate async, and then await the Task.Delay call or use a timer. Making the delegate async would look like this:

```
        btn.Click += async delegate
        {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                text1.Text = i.ToString();
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, it work.I think I should read some documentation about async, can you help me with some links?

Comment: @AlexAlexiuc Try this one for a start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx